# How can I convert string '4 days, 23:56:46.063070' to integer 119.9977 in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Title says it all. I have a string in date/time format and I'm not sure how to convert it to decimal. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime
import re

timestr = '4 days, 23:56:46.063070'
matches = re.match('(\d+) days, (.*)', timestr)
assert matches
days = int(matches.group(1))
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(matches.group(2), '%H:%M:%S.%f')
timediff = time - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1) # timedelta
hours = days*24 + timediff.total_seconds()/60/60
```

By the way that gives 119.946 not 119.997.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Timedelta("4 days, 23:56:46.063070") / pd.Timedelta(1, 'h')
119.94612863055555
```